# Rails3: uninitialized constant Mime::MOBILE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile, mime-types

I use [mobile-fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu) to automatically detect mobile devices that access My Rails application.

When My rails version is 3.2.8

my config/initializers/mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
```

My WelcomeController

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.mobile 
    format.html
  end
end
```

When I visit welcome/indx , I got this error:

```
uninitialized constant Mime::MOBILE
```

When I change rails to 3.2.3 , It works fine.

Is anybody know that?

Thanks!

Comment: have you included has_mobile_fu in your controller ?

Comment: @chucai ever figure this out?